# Animate for onclick on submit button only works in FF (not IE nor OP)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Does anybody know why the following code only has effect in FF?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#powerSearchSubmitButton').click(function() {
        startLoad();
    });
});

function startLoad() {
    $('.message').each(function(i) {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500);           
    });
};
```

Comment: Why is commented code and the if statements there? It'll be better if you provide the minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Pretty much a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333911/jquery-animate-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie

Comment: This is javascript? What do the dollar signs do?

Comment: @Albert He's using a JavaScript library called jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update****

Example here http://pastebin.me/4937b07714655 of 1 option which is to keep a count of the messages and run the animation callback only on the last message.

---

why dont you return false from the click or event.preventDefault() and in the animation callback submit the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#powerSearchSubmitButton').click(function(ev) {
        startLoad();
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});

function startLoad() {
    var $messages=$('.message');
    var count=$messages.length -1;
    $messages.each(function(i) {
       $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, i == count ? submitForm:null);           
    });
};

function submitForm(){
     $('#yourForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: Great idea, I'll come back with feedback when I got to it :)

Comment: By attaching a submitForm to the callback from each .message, I would get a number of submits.
Can I somehow implement a callback from the entire startLoad function (I should rename it to animateLoad or something)

Comment: boris a number of ways you could count the number of items $('.message').length and keep a counter so you know ehn the last one has fired and then call the submitForm event. You could even use a setTimeout after 750ms say when you can be sure 99% of the animation is done. See which one works best

Comment: errr I'll clarify in my answer!

Comment: Thanks, I went with the count and a isSubmitted toggle. the count is what you described, the isSubmitted toggle to prevent double submits.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'return false;' to your click function. I set up a demo [on my site](http://www.sanchothefat.com/dev/sfhelp/ie-opera-not-running-jquery-animation.html) and it works fine in IE6 and Opera.

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't tell if that's what you needed to do. You've got the answer now anyway - just submit via javascript once all the animations are finished.