# Jquery problem with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

I use this piece of code to animate horizontal scroll, but don't work in IE!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#next').click(function() {
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollLeft:"+="+500},1000); 
        $('#prev a').show();
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollLeft:"-="+500},1000 );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check this question for any answers related to jQuery and IE. [jquery-animate-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333911/jquery-animate-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, try using this selector instead:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({...
```